# Find the nth derivative of $\exp(ax)\sin(bx+c)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

[image: Nth derivative]

The quality of the picture isn't really good. I found out the first 3 derivatives and sort of did some guesswork. I don't know if the nth derivative is correct and l don't know how to get it into a closed-form.

Is there another approach to finding the nth derivative that is easier?

Is this method correct ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$n$th derivative of $e^{ax}\sin(bx+c)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3330589/nth-derivative-of-eax-sinbxc)

Comment: @an4s I want to see if the method l used can get me the nth derivative or is it a dead end ? The methods in those answers are right but they look a little more complicated.

Comment: They are in fact much simpler and efficient.

Comment: @Yves Daoust I think this is a duplicate and that approach does answer my question. Can you provide a hint on completing the steps above and then you can close this question as duplicate . Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no need for so many terms. Simply write $f^{(n)}(x)=e^{ax}(u_n\sin(bx+c)+v_n\cos(bx+c))$ and develop a recurrence for $u_n$ and $v_n$.

Comment: @Simply Beautiful Art How do we define or present the recurrence in a compact form. Is there a closed expression for u and v. Thanks in advance

Comment: That is more or less handled in the duplicate link.